# How do I handle binding to an entity that doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to understand how binding works between the view model and page controls when on a 'New Item' page. For example:

**TransactionView.xaml.cs**

```
public TransactionsView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = App.ViewModel;
}
```

If I have a list of Transactions, I would do something like this, where `AllTransactions` is of type `ObservableCollection`.

```
<ListBox Margin="12,15,12,0" Height="Auto" x:Name="lb_Transactions"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllTransactions}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TransListDataTemplate}">
</ListBox>
```

What happens when I have a 'New Transaction' page, which contains a simple form that contains input controls for the user to input text. When the user clicks save, I would create a new `Transaction` object, populate it using the data from the form, and add it using `App.ViewModel.SaveTransaction()`.

What do I bind the controls in the UI on the `New` form to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably create a new `Transaction` first then open the dialog which only manipulates said transaction (pass in constructor and save reference in a property for binding). If the dialog is confirmed the object can be added to the collection, if it is cancelled the object can just be ignored (and go out of scope if created as local variable).

Comment: So you are saying to create a new `Transaction` object, which is bound to the 'new' form. Then, if all input is validated, add it to the view model?

Comment: Yes, that is what i am saying. If the `Transaction` cannot be constructed beforehand you best add all the input properties in the new-form and bind to those instead, just less convenient.

Comment: Thanks H.B.! I'm VERY new to the MVVM & binding concept, but this got me where I was going. I guess I WAS on the right path before.

Comment: Err, i am far from being a specialist in MVVM, so you may want to get some other views on this or maybe check if what you end up doing still conforms to the pattern (as i did not really think much of the VM, which in my suggested case would probably just contain the model).